# Yii2. Not able to save big file to BLOB database field

Tags: mysql, yii2, blob

I use following code in order to save a file:

```
$file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'uploadedFile');//Get the uploaded file
$fp = fopen($file->tempName, 'r');
//$content = fread($fp, filesize($file->tempName));
$content = file_get_contents($file->tempName);
fclose($fp);
$model->content = $content;
$model->save();
```

With mentioned code I can save files up to approximately 1 MB. But larger files throw an error after `$model->save()`:

```
PDOStatement::execute(): MySQL server has gone away
```

I use `mediumblob` type. What can be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a `max_allowed_packet = 1M` inside `my.ini`.